# ts() function - defining unique quartiles

Tags: r, time-series

I have a dataset that looks something like this (below).

I'm trying to convert this data to a ts() object by grouping the data by the Seasons column as the listed seasons.  So for example Q1 would be SU15, and Q2 would be FA15 and so on.  Also, not all seasons have the same number of data points.  I've tried doing

```
 DF_ts <- ts(DF$Variable, frequency = 52, 
           start=decimal_date(ymd(DF$Date[1])))

DF_ts_2 <- aggregate(each_style_ts, nfrequency=4)
```

but I noticed that the Quartiles not grouped the way I want them to.  I also have a very large dataset I'm doing this for, so it needs to be somewhat automated.  The example below is merely just that..an example. I also need to ensure that they are in order: (ie: SUMMER 2015, FALL 2015, WINTER 2015, SPRING 2016)

```html
Date Season Variable
6/20/15 SU15 67859
6/27/15 SU15 75251
7/4/15 SU15 100085
7/11/15 FA15 98760
7/18/15 FA15 95053
7/25/15 FA15 91286
8/1/15 FA15 88573
8/8/15 FA15 23084
8/15/15 FA15 31939
8/22/15 FA15 31445
8/29/15 FA15 30854
9/5/15 FA15 21890
9/12/15 FA15 29948
9/19/15 FA15 54254
9/26/15 FA15 52819
10/3/15 FA15 51974
10/10/15 WN15 55826
10/17/15 WN15 53300
10/24/15 WN15 52442
10/31/15 WN15 23084
11/7/15 WN15 31939
11/14/15 WN15 31445
11/21/15 WN15 30854
11/28/15 WN15 21890
12/5/15 WN15 29948
12/12/15 WN15 54254
12/19/15 WN15 52819
12/26/15 WN15 51974
1/2/16 WN15 55826
1/9/16 SP16 53300
1/16/16 SP16 52442
1/23/16 SP16 23084
1/30/16 SP16 31939
2/6/16 SP16 31445
2/13/16 SP16 30854
2/20/16 SP16 21890
2/27/16 SP16 29948
3/5/16 SP16 54254
3/12/16 SP16 52819
3/19/16 SP16 51974
3/26/16 SP16 55826
4/2/16 SP16 53300
```

**Data in dput format.**

```
DF <-
structure(list(Date = structure(c(28L, 29L, 33L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
34L, 38L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 42L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
10L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 22L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 26L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 33L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 38L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 42L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 9L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 18L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 2L, 
5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 22L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 26L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 27L), .Label = c("1/16/16", 
"1/2/16", "1/23/16", "1/30/16", "1/9/16", "10/10/15", "10/17/15", 
"10/24/15", "10/3/15", "10/31/15", "11/14/15", "11/21/15", "11/28/15", 
"11/7/15", "12/12/15", "12/19/15", "12/26/15", "12/5/15", "2/13/16", 
"2/20/16", "2/27/16", "2/6/16", "3/12/16", "3/19/16", "3/26/16", 
"3/5/16", "4/2/16", "6/20/15", "6/27/15", "7/11/15", "7/18/15", 
"7/25/15", "7/4/15", "8/1/15", "8/15/15", "8/22/15", "8/29/15", 
"8/8/15", "9/12/15", "9/19/15", "9/26/15", "9/5/15"), class = "factor"), 
    Season = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("FA15", "SP16", "SU15", "WN15"), class = "factor"), 
    Variable = c(67859L, 75251L, 100085L, 98760L, 95053L, 91286L, 
    88573L, 23084L, 31939L, 31445L, 30854L, 21890L, 29948L, 54254L, 
    52819L, 51974L, 55826L, 53300L, 52442L, 23084L, 31939L, 31445L, 
    30854L, 21890L, 29948L, 54254L, 52819L, 51974L, 55826L, 53300L, 
    52442L, 23084L, 31939L, 31445L, 30854L, 21890L, 29948L, 54254L, 
    52819L, 51974L, 55826L, 53300L, 67859L, 75251L, 100085L, 
    98760L, 95053L, 91286L, 88573L, 23084L, 31939L, 31445L, 30854L, 
    21890L, 29948L, 54254L, 52819L, 51974L, 55826L, 53300L, 52442L, 
    23084L, 31939L, 31445L, 30854L, 21890L, 29948L, 54254L, 52819L, 
    51974L, 55826L, 53300L, 52442L, 23084L, 31939L, 31445L, 30854L, 
    21890L, 29948L, 54254L, 52819L, 51974L, 55826L, 53300L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-84L))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `mdy()` to convert `DF$Date` to an object of class `Date`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the following is what you want.
I use package `zoo` in order to `aggregate.zoo` the time series by quarters. The package has a `as.yearqtr` function that returns the quarters given a date.

```
library(zoo)

DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%m/%d/%y")

z <- zoo(DF$Variable, order.by = DF$Date)
aggregate(z, as.yearqtr(index(z)))
#2015 Q2 2015 Q3 2015 Q4 2016 Q1 2016 Q2 
# 286220 1499980 1083498 1091202  106600
```

Answer (score 0):

The question never defines what output is desired so we assume we want to find the mean value of `Variable` for each year/quarter as a `ts` series.

Compute the two letter season, `season`, and from that the quarter `qtr` such that `SP` is quarter 1, `SU` is quarter 2, etc.  Also compute the two digit year `yy` and from that compute a `"yearqtr"` class object `yq`.  Then aggregate `zoo(Variable)` by `yq` using `mean`.  (If some different aggregation function instead of `mean` is wanted just replace `mean` with it.)  Finally convert the resulting zoo object `ag` to ts.

```
library(zoo)

season <- gsub("\\d", "", DF$Season)
qtr <- match(season, c("SP", "SU", "FA", "WN"))
yy <- sub("..", "", DF$Season)
yq <- as.yearqtr(paste(yy, qtr), "%y %q")

ag <- aggregate(zoo(DF$Variable), yq, mean)
as.ts(ag)
```

giving:

```
         Qtr1     Qtr2     Qtr3     Qtr4
2015          81065.00 53990.69 41969.31
2016 41775.00
```